# Hard reset to a previous git Commit - Not working

Tags: git, git-commit, git-remote, git-reset, git-revert

I have run

```
git log
```

And find this-

```
    C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero [panelist_qa_AJAX_solution]> git log
    commit afbda8a710aab851937532543bb0a99f246874e3
    Merge: 19323e3 cfde9ef
    Author: S. M. Abrar Jahin <abrarjahin@live.com>
    Date:   Sun Oct 11 00:51:40 2015 +0600

        Merge branch 'panelist_qa_AJAX_solution' of https://github.com/techmarket/gtwhero into panelist_qa_AJAX_solution

    commit 19323e3d1c8055c324a7ed65c3868e92420aad9f
    Author: S. M. Abrar Jahin <abrarjahin@live.com>
    Date:   Sun Oct 11 00:48:43 2015 +0600

        nothing

    commit cfde9eff38fccd15dfc521e7ba075622a31a5a6e
    Merge: 38a68bd b773dd2
    Author: Platon <heonozis@mail.ru>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 17:08:30 2015 +0300

        Merge remote-tracking branch 'remotes/origin/master' into panelist_qa_AJAX_solution

        Conflicts:
            app/Http/Controllers/WebinarController.php

    commit b773dd225b8ffa34cb9231a4e58063756d7e53f1
    Merge: 1d9923d 21f19e3
    Author: Platon Mysnyk <Heonozis@mail.ru>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 16:04:29 2015 +0300

        Merge pull request #98 from techmarket/fix-webinar-hosts-all-questions-issue

        Fix webinar hosts all questions issue

    commit 21f19e3585329d3d2006e32254ff62808b241f90
    Author: Ronak <coolronak.shah@rediffmail.com>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 16:27:21 2015 +0530

        Reverse the QA order in Webinar host Layout

    commit ea539597995011952b2ca083ae61b4ca1c4176aa
    Author: Ronak <coolronak.shah@rediffmail.com>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 16:12:28 2015 +0530

        Fix Webinar Host Layout QA section update and Also changed the Alert message for Vote chart refreshed in host layo
    commit 38a68bda7d0e7c13d92bf42f791f9c3e805d909d
    Author: S. M. Abrar Jahin <abrarjahin@live.com>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 16:23:39 2015 +0600

        "panelist_id" and auth fix with help of @Ronak

    commit 3ba2bfea5d7ad8ff4a83b23595c7a9841bc064b2
    Author: S. M. Abrar Jahin <abrarjahin@live.com>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 13:31:08 2015 +0600

        Animation for removing item

    commit 2181c108c76f187c09744ae6df131f8f80f0b16d
    Author: S. M. Abrar Jahin <abrarjahin@live.com>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 12:27:53 2015 +0600

        Animation Added in QA

    commit 180337bfe91686d137e3222c196e626f712832b1
    Author: S. M. Abrar Jahin <abrarjahin@live.com>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 12:17:34 2015 +0600

        All AJAX of this page "http://localhost/gtwhero/public/webinar/LB42JgKdjEAOAe5b37MV/panelist" done

    commit e25c6c19605627a00ca033139c2d98af0feacacf
    Author: S. M. Abrar Jahin <abrarjahin@live.com>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 07:45:42 2015 +0600

        Before breakfast - done, remaining AJAX query
```

The code is already pushed in github.

I want to go back to the state when I have made a commit-

```
    commit 3ba2bfea5d7ad8ff4a83b23595c7a9841bc064b2
    Author: S. M. Abrar Jahin <abrarjahin@live.com>
    Date:   Sat Oct 10 13:31:08 2015 +0600

        Animation for removing item
```

So, what I had tried is-

> git reset --hard 3ba2bfea5d7ad8ff4a83b23595c7a9841bc064b2

When I run it, it says, "**HEAD is now at 3ba2bfe Animation for removing item**"

But I am finding that, it is not the state when I had made the commmit.

What can I do, can anyone please help?

Comment: _it is not the state when I had made the commmit_ - How do you know that?

Comment: Because I have checked the file's output.

It were not the same

Comment: @AbrarJahin Whatever uncommitted changes may have been in your working directory (and/or index) at the time you made the commit in question have been obliterated by your use of the `--hard` flag.

Comment: @AbrarJahin When you say "the file's output" do you mean you ran the code and you got different output? If it's that, maybe something else changed. Or do you mean the checked in files themselves are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run it, it says, "HEAD is now at 3ba2bfe Animation for removing item". But I am finding that, it is not the state when I had made the commit.

*The branch you were on when you ran reset*, as well as your checkout, is now at 3ba2bfe.  If the content is not what you expected it to be, with respect, you've mis-remembered that commit.  You can check by checking out that commit, `git checkout 3ba2bfe`, and looking at the content or `git show 3ba2bfe` to see the diff.

The only other explanation is when you say "it is not the state when I had made the commit" that "it" is something else. I assume you're referring to your local branch. Or are you talking about the branch on Github?